# Is it common practice to fill a KYC questionnaire for a P2P lending service?

Tags: scams, peer-to-peer-lending, know-your-customer

I am using a P2P lending platform since about a year ago. When Coronavirus pandemic started, they freezed all the withdrawals and deposits from the investors (me). So I haven't been able to withdraw money from my account.

Since then, they sent around 3 or 4 emails to us saying basically not to worry and they're dealing with this.

Today I received an email from them asking to fill out a KYC questionnaire with some of the details being these:

> address of actual residence, place of birth, extended fields about PEP
> (politically exposed person), income, beneficiary information,
> financial transaction information and other fields

Is this a normal procedure? Is it okay to fill the questionnaire? I am hesitant about this, because I feel like this is just a buying time tactic and might be used by them to find some 'legal appeal' for being justified in not returning money to investors.

Comment: *P2P platform* means you lend money to other people?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler yes, my platform specifically lends to businesses and development projects

Comment: Sounds a bit like the platform found out that what they are doing and the way they are doing it is not exactly legal and are now in damage control mode.

Comment: @Philipp I might need to add some more info. I had already put the data such as my name, passport info, type of income, and Tax residence country. What they want now is to update that section and add new data such as my earnings, my monthly investments, monthly transactions etc...

Comment: I work for a company that does online onboarding for investment firms (RRSPs, IRAs, etc.)  Not the same kind of program you're describing, but similar industry, I guess.  We *do* ask for all this information you mention, but we ask for it when *opening a new client account.* Not after clients have been signed up for a year.  It may not be an outright scam, but something fishy is definitely going on here.

Comment: Naming the platform you're using might help flush out some more information.

Comment: @timday, the platform is called Grupeer

Comment: Their info at https://www.grupeer.com/faq is interesting.  The stuff under the "How is it possible that so many of your investors have not submitted KYC questionnaires?" in particular supports @Philipp's comment above that they may have been rather sloppy in following the rules.  There's another thing there that makes it clear you'll have to submit the info to withdraw funds when it does become possible.  Recent update https://www.grupeer.com/blog/know-your-client-questionnaire-update/ also interesting.  However I don't know enough about the P2P world to know what's normal and what's scammy.

Comment: ...however things like https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.grupeer.com and https://www.p2pfinancenews.co.uk/2020/06/02/p2p-investors-plot-legal-action-against-grupeer/ hardly look good for them.

Comment: @timday yeah the trustpilot reviews started going low the moment they stopped investors from being able to withdraw their money.